# Easiest way to install single file via rpm

Tags: rpm

I would like to deliver a jar to the classpath of our yarn cluster and rpm is a requirement.

What is the easiest way to build rpm that will put jar file `Foo` in path `Bar`?

I hope there is some one-liner to do this. I've tried researching "rpm-building" topic but it seems pretty complicated.

Comment: There are many tutorials available, I found one [with a 15s search](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/package-management/build-a-simple-rpm-that-packages-a-single-file.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest possible solution using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm):

```
mkdir -p var/lib/xxx
touch var/lib/xxx/yyy
fpm -s dir -t rpm -n yyy var/lib/xxx/yyy
```